# Is there anyway to give this value to my node

Tags: c, constants, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have a school project where I need to create a doubly linked list.

In one of my functions I want to create a new node and add a value to it but it doesn't work.

The function name and parameters can't be changed and I need to put this const declared string into a non-const declared string.

```
static struct node *make_node(const char *value)
{
  struct node *node;
  node = malloc(sizeof(node));
  node->value = value;

  return node;
}
```

I get the error message:

> warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target
>   type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current code does is simply copy the address of one string (the given parameter) to the other (the `struct` data member). This is why the compiler generates the warning: the "parameter" value points to a string that cannot be changed; the "struct" value points to one that can be changed.

In order to copy the *actual string data*, you would first need to allocate enough memory to hold the string data, then copy the data to it:

```c
static struct node *make_node(const char *value)
{
    struct node *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node->value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1); // Add 1 to accommodate the nul-terminator
    strcpy(node->value, value);
//  node->value = value;
    return node;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function (this will do the allocation and copying for you):

```c
node->value = strdup(value);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification/explanation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch took your advice and created a new function that does just this, appreciate it!